# need to compare two columns from two files and write all columns to new file using unix

Tags: unix

I have 2 files in unix environment

file1:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

file2:

```
----------
## Heading ##

2 bb
1 aa
3 cc
```

how to get the output file

output:

```
1 a 1 aa
2 b 2 bb
3 c 3 cc
```

using unix shell scripting

Comment: please find file details file1 
1 a
2 b
3 c
file2
b 22
a 11
c 33

output
1 a a 11
2 b b 22
3 c c 33

Comment: There's a special site for that: https://superuser.com/

Comment: Also, `man 1 paste`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk. This is an awk classic:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$0}' file1 file2
2 b 2 bb
1 a 1 aa
3 c 3 cc
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {             # process first file
    a[$1]=$0          # hash record, use first field as hash key
    next              # move to next record
}
$1 in a {             # second file, if key found in the hash
    print a[$1],$0    # output it from the hash along with the current record
}' file1 file2        # mind the order
```

Order will be the second file order. If you want it in some other order, either sort `file2` (`awk ... file1 <(sort file2)`) or the output of the awk process (`awk ... | sort`).

Comment: `paste`. it's called `paste`. Also, it's the perfect example of the [law of the hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) :)

Comment: @iehrlich Yeah I know. Just trying to live to the definition (_question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers_ :) (btw did you mean `join`?)